# Notice: Undefined index: 2aad888f2b4ac316b016a9a0bda1c329 on line 16

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to make an email activation script in php and what you see above (2aad888f2b4ac316b016a9a0bda1c329) is this users unique activation key. What do you think the problem is?
Here is my NEW code:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password="power1"; 
$db_name="members"; 
$tbl_name="users";

$link  = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect. Please contact us");
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB. Please contact us");

$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

if(isset($_SESSION[$queryString])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$_SESSION[$queryString]'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($queryString == $row[activationkey]){
        echo "Congratulations! You have succesfully activated you account. You may now login.";

        $sql = ("UPDATE users SET activationkey='' AND status='activated' WHERE username=".$row['username']);

        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
}


?>
```

Comment: It says that the variable/index `$_SESSION['2aad888f2b4ac316b016a9a0bda1c329']` doesn't exist. Fix that.

Comment: $_SESSION doesn't exist?

Comment: No, **`$_SESSION['2aad888f2b4ac316b016a9a0bda1c329']`** doesn't exist.

Comment: but that cant exist becuase that key is not always going to be there those keys are random

Answer (score 1):

> `$_SESSION['2aad888f2b4ac316b016a9a0bda1c329']` doesn't exist.
>
> *"but that cant exist becuase that key is not always going to be there those keys are random"*

Then your error is in this line, trying to access that key anyway:

```
$uemail = $_SESSION["$queryString"];
```

Maybe you need to check with [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) whether the key actually exists before accessing it, or change something in your program logic to prevent this case.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: hehe, once you wrap variable with double quotes - god kills a kitten? ;-)

Comment: I thought I'd quibble about this *after* the basics were cleared up... ;)

Comment: @deceze: just confess that you don't like kittens ;-)

Comment: @zerkms You're right, I hate `"$kittens"`! `"$kittens"`, `"$kittens"`, `"$kittens"`. >:-D

Answer (score -1):

```
$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password="power1"; 
$db_name="members"; 
$tbl_name="users";

$link  = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect. Please contact us");
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB. Please contact us");

$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

if(isset($_SESSION["$queryString")) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$_SESSION["$queryString"]'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if ($queryString == $row[activationkey]){
            echo "Congratulations! You have succesfully activated you account. You may now login.";

            $sql = ("UPDATE users SET activationkey='' AND status='activated' WHERE username=".$row['username']);

            if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have any more spoons.